# Are some of the conditions of the alternating series test neccesary?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

The alternating series test says that if $a_n$ is a sequence such that 
\begin{align} (a) a_n\geq 0\\
(b) a_n\rightarrow 0\\
(c) a_{n+1}<a_n,
\end{align}
then the series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^na_n$$ converges.
Question: Is there any example of a divergent  series satisfying $(a)$ and $(c)$ but not $(b)$.

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1306387/8157)

Comment: The usual statement has $a_n >0$ and $a_{n+1} \le a_n$ instead of your (a) and (c). This is a little more general than your statement and sidesteps Hagen von Eitzen's point that your (b) and (c) imply your (a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Let $a_n=1+\frac1n$.

However, can there be a sequence with (b) and (c), but not (a)?